# Internal Server Error upon installation

Tags: 500-internal-error, internal-server-error

I'm developping a website using wordpress, i got domain name, i accessed the cpanel, and I installed Wordpress using Softaculous. The problem is when the installation is complete, I try to open the link but I get this error

> **Internal Server Error**
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@domainName.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Wordpress, I tried the same thing with Prestashop and i got the same issue.

`domainName.com` and `domainName.com\wp-admin` both get me the same error

PHP version is **5.6**  and Wordpress version is **5.3**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to change the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.3 (or 7.4). Also, check your htaccess file because broken .htaccess files might cause that issue. If the issue still persists, then check "error.log" file in order to see what the problem is.